# How useful is Function.name property?

Tags: javascript

```
var func1 = function() {}
console.log(func1.name); // func1
```

Is there any real-time usage of this property from the javascript developer's perspective?

Comment: You can pass this function name to third function that tells if it's setter or getter and applies proper common algorithm. Also you can log function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it for debugging purposes when you pass function as a parameter to another function, for instance:

```js
var fun1 = function(){};

function fun2(){};

var g = function(f){
    console.log("Invoking " + f.name);
    f();
}

if(Math.random() > 0.5){
    g(fun1);
} else {
    g(fun2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question will be quite broad, since there are hundreds of examples for the usage of property called `name`. They are covered in detail in JavaScript [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). Few of the examples are following.

**Changing the function name.**

```
var newName = "xyzName";
var f = function () {};
Object.defineProperty(f, 'name', {value: newName});
console.log(f.name); // will output xyzName
```

**For logging the class stack we can get the constructor name as in the following example.**

```
function a() {};
var b = new a();
console.log(b.constructor.name); // will output a
```

**Get the function name if it's not anonymous.**

```
var getRectArea = function area(width, height) {
    return width * height;
}
getRectArea.name; //will output area
```

Comment: The question itself is also quite broad and opinion based and should be closed, not answered. "Not all questions can or should be answered here." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob, I agree... I answered because it got so many votes in just one hour, and the accepted answer did not mention that it has vast usage.